# Need help to log the function body using firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox

When we use the console.log(someObject.someFunction) firebug shows function() string only.

Is there a way i can see/log the code for the function in the console window ? Something similar to what we can achieve using alert(someObject.someFunction) shows the function body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myFunction.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
console.log(myFunction + '');
```